# How can I move a mistakenly placed TFS branch?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have just branched from Main to v5.0 but I realized that I want to move this branch inside the Release folder.

How should I proceed with TFS 2010?

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Simply right-click on your branch in Source Control and select 'Move..'. Set your desired destination path, and commit this change. You should be OK.
I think I 've read somewhere that moving folders & renaming folders shouldn't be done in separate steps, so if you plan to also rename your branch, do this in a next step.
Once you 're done, you should check that with right-clicking MAIN > "branching and merging" > "merge..." you have a target branch to your moved/renamed branch.

Comment: Just need to make sure the branch's parent folder is mapped to the workspace.  Otherwise "Move" is grayed out.

Comment: Ah, that's what threw me off -- I had the branch cloaked, had to uncloak it and get latest. -- Kind of a bizarre requirement for a branch level operation though (i.e. it seems like a branch level operation should be doable completely on the server-side, without giving my local machine a chance to derp things up.)