# Move a project from root into a branch directory?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, branch

I have created some projects into the root of a TFS Project. Now I need to create a V2 Branch from it. Now I think, it would be better to have the following structure:

- root

  - v1

    - proj1
    - proj2
  - v2

    - proj1
    - proj2

I have taken a look, into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382636/how-can-i-move-a-mistakenly-placed-tfs-branch) Question, but the move option is greyed out. A comment is suggesting to map the parent, but the parent is the root, which is already mapped.

How can I move all projects in the root, into a V1 Folder?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the moving, you need to create a workspace first. **Confirm your workspace path, map your workspace, and get the source.**
[image]

More details please refer this tutorial: [Configure your workspace](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs#configure-your-workspace)

Since all your projects are grayed and the *move, rename , delete* button is also grayed. You need to get the projects which you want to move and the branch V2 folder to local.

After this, the *move* button will be black and you will be able to move project. Check in pending changes, tfs will do a **delete**(delete the projects in old path) and **add**(add them to new path under branchV2) operation.

Comment: I had to remove my workspace and Map&Get again somehow.